# How can I tell the update manager to never update my Nvidia drivers?

Tags: nvidia

I had set my Nvidia , and it is working. My CUDA compiler in Ubuntu is now working.

Now, I do not want Sotware Center update my nvidia at all... , how can I force software center not update my Nvidia graphix card at all? If somebody know how to remove automatic update from Software Center please let know.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to put the packages on hold. See this excellent post on how to:

[How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package/18656#18656)

Answer (score 0):

This documentation page contains instructions for putting a hold on a package, both on the command line and using the synaptic package manager (the latter is probably easier, providing synaptic is installed).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto

The package you want to lock is probably "nvidia-current".

I am not sure how this will interact with a future distribution upgrade. You may need to manually unpin the package before doing so.